# Temperature meaning

Tags: temperature, entropy

They say that the vibrational kinetic energy is a measure of temperature. Temperature is also related to the entropy as the partial differential. It is a measure of the energy of the atoms within but which types of energy? Say hydrogen bonding increases with a decrease in temperature not the other way around. Which types of energy other than kinetic of the molecules increase with temperature including bonds? How heat transfer between the molecules with temperature difference but not with actual motion? Though actual motion collisions can result in an increase in temperature from stress for example

Comment: The answers to the example in this question illustrates the difference between thermodynamic definition and the statistical   https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/548965/ . it may help.

Comment: Yes but i believe $$ T_{\text{kinetic}}=\frac{2}{3k}\left[\overline{\frac 1 2 m v^2}\right]=\frac{2}{3k}\text{KE}_{\text{average}} $$ is true only for monoatomic ideal gases and there is no real explanation for how heat transfer occurs on the molecular level. How can we derive the thermal conductivity/specific heat capacity from molecular properties? Also as Temperature is the partial of the internal energy wrt entropy then using the Sackur-Tetrode eqn we get the above formula but there are additional concerns for diatomic molecules

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-Sackur-Tetrode-equation-for-non-monatomic-gases you can see but what are the physical forces that they are talking about?

Comment: The thermal energy is the sum of the vibrational, rotational and kinetic energies

Comment: for specific heat  see https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/sm1/Thermal.pdf page 143 or so. again it is only in ideal gases. But it is enough to prove mathematically that the thermodynamic quantity arises from the statistical behavior. Then one uses the simple thermodynamic formulae. for forces, rmember that dp/dt is the definition of force.

Comment: yes but if the thermal energy is the sum of the vibrational, rotational and kinetic energies of the molecules then why is the thermal conductivity related to the electrical conductivity

Comment: I would guess it happens when the electrons are the main carriers. found this https://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/thermal_electrical/printall.php

Comment: ahh i guess this is how the thermal hall effect and thermocouples work